# How to compare my current location Lat and Log with a radius of 3 miles ? Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I already have the user's current location in form of Lat and Lon in my view controller , what I'm missing is comparing those user location with a file or gpx of the location that I want to compare to , my idea is that when the user drives or get the place for example a college the app will said "welcome to blag bla college ...

Thanks . I'm using Xcode and swift .

Comment: Have you looked at Core Location region monitoring via CLCircularRegion?

Answer (score 1):

Create a CLLocation object for the user's location, and another one for the second location. then use the CLLocation method `distanceFromLocation:` to calculate the distance.